# Select next Text Box after the value is Entered jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, input, textbox, slider

I have an array of

```
<input type="range"> text boxes.
```

When the submit is clicked the value of the slider is sent to the select box.

I was wondering if it is possible to select the next box when submit is clicked instead of clicking on the box itself.

here the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/salvonostrato/hygc6/

thanks

Comment: check which element is focused, then make focus to the next element.

Comment: This is where i get stuck. I cannot find the right function to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove current `clicked` class from element and change `background` color to `red` then find the `next` text box. Then add `clicked` class, then change `background` color to `white`.

Just use this piece of code within `#ok`'s `click` event listener.

```
    $('.clicked').removeClass('clicked').css({
        background: "red"
    }).next().next('[type=text]').addClass('clicked').css({
        background: "white"
    });
```

<kbd>**[SEE THIS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/b4Fne/)**</kbd>

**UPDATE :**

You have a another weapon in your hand. That is, you are using `.freqbox` class in your all `input` boxes. So, You can find the last element of `.freqbox`by `.freqbox:last` and first element of `.freqbox` using `.freqbox:first`.

So, your code will be like this,

```
if ($('.clicked').is('.freqbox:last')) {
            alert('true');
            $('.clicked').removeClass('clicked').css({
                background: "red"
            }).siblings('.freqbox:first').addClass('clicked').css({
                background: "white"
            });
        } else {
            alert('false');
            $('.clicked').removeClass('clicked').css({
                background: "red"
            }).next().next('[type=text]').addClass('clicked').css({
                background: "white"
            });
        }
```

<kbd>**[SEE THIS UPDATED FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/b4Fne/4/)**</kbd>

Comment: this is great. Thank you this answered my question 100%. Is there a way to start again once the last box is updated?

Comment: Thank you very much Ramki. Very helpful .. happy easter